# Allocating Max Memory in R

Tags: r, memory, size, ram

I got the following error message in R relating to memory:

```
Error: cannot allocate vector of size 7.5 Gb
```

I was reading that there are ways in R/R Studio to allocate more memory compared to what is currently available.

I tried using the following command, but got the following error:

```
> memory.limit(size=2500)
[1] 7831
Warning message:
In memory.limit(size = 2500) : cannot decrease memory limit: ignored
```

I tried to find out how much I currently have:

```
get_free_ram <- function(){
    if(Sys.info()[["sysname"]] == "Windows"){
        x <- system2("wmic", args =  "OS get FreePhysicalMemory /Value", stdout = TRUE)
        x <- x[grepl("FreePhysicalMemory", x)]
        x <- gsub("FreePhysicalMemory=", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
        x <- gsub("\r", "", x, fixed = TRUE)
        as.integer(x)
    } else {
        stop("Only supported on Windows OS")
    }
}
```

I also tried this:

```
> get_free_ram()
[1] 323076

> gc()
           used  (Mb) gc trigger (Mb)   max used   (Mb)
Ncells  2038194 108.9    6346452  339    7933065  423.7
Vcells 14755424 112.6  975825445 7445 1015087309 7744.6
```

- **In short : I understand there is a limit - but is there some way in R to allocate the max amount of memory/RAM that your computer is able to do?**

Thank you!

```
#Further Notes:

> sessionInfo()
R version 4.1.3 (2022-03-10)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 22000)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_Canada.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_Canada.1252    LC_MONETARY=English_Canada.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                   
[5] LC_TIME=English_Canada.1252
```

Comment: And why do you want to do that? The best way is to tackle the problem using a different approach. Probably have the data in a drive and read chunks of it at a time

Comment: First, you need to understand that the message is about *additional*  memory demand, *not*  about total memory demand. It shouldn't be necessary to worry about R's memory limits. It's a fool's errand to play with them unless your goal is to restrict them further. I'm pretty sure your system doesn't have enough RAM for what you are trying to do.